# Webapp authenticate with rest API

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

This is a pretty general question. Imagine a modern "single-page" javascript web application, which relies in AJAX call to a rest API for data access.

The rest API is only accessible by providing a unique token, that is registered to the user. The token can be retrieved (or created) by supplying username and password some endpoint, e.g. `/login`.

Now, once the user has retrieved the token, how can I store it? I know of a few possible ways, but I do not know what is safe to do.

**Store it in a cookie**: Nope! Cause cookies are exposed to the file system and can easily be compromised.

**Store it in localstorage in the browser**: Well, probably not. Local storage is accessible by any page you go to, so a malicious site with a scraping feature might pick it up.

**Store it in memory in javascript until user leaves the page**: This should be relatively safe, I'd assume. But what if I want to remember the login between visits? Would I then have to keep a session on the server? And if I need this session, what is even the point of using the token? Might as well just resend username and password on every request instead, right?

Any other solution I havn't thought of? How do people do this?

Comment: I would not say your own file system is easily compromised to an attacker. Cookies are the mostly used to store API keys: just remember to encrypt the transfer between client and server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/), which provide a great walkthrough of what to be aware of.

In short terms: Localstorage is very hard to keep safe from XSS or security errors in code, since it is accessible through javascript. Cookies used to store session keys are not restful, since state is stored on the server, however, they can be used to store access tokens like JWT's, which can be made safe if the cookie is `HttpOnly;` and `Secure;`

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong on a few accounts:

> Store it in a cookie: Nope! Cause cookies are exposed to the file system and can easily be compromised.

Using cookies is generally a pretty acceptable place to store secrets. Many people do. I would say that the risk is not so much that it's stored on the filesystem (if a hacker has access to the filesystem, any sort of protection will be gone), but moreso that it gets submitted very every request, which opens the door to CSRF. If you don't need it, and you can avoid it, nice!

> Store it in localstorage in the browser: Well, probably not. Local storage is accessible by any page you go to, so a malicious site with a scraping feature might pick it up.

It's actually not accessible by any page, just by your sandbox (your domain, generally), so this has the benefits of cookies, without the drawbacks.

Comment: If localstorage is safe in all browsers, that might be the solution then